# Passing array via Ajax to MVC Action

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following code for my controller action

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> MonthsToAdd(List<string> months)

{

}
```

My ajax code looks like as follows

```
$("#btnSave").on("click", function () {
 var months= [];
 var value = $("input[name=monthsAvailable]:checked").val()
 var lengths = $("input[value=" + value + "]").closest(".row").index()
  console.log($("input[value=" + value + "]").closest(".row").index())
  for (var i = 0; i <= lengths; i++) {
     months.push($(".outer .row:eq(" + i + ") input:radio").val())
  }

console.log(JSON.stringify(months));
$.ajax({
  contentType: 'application/json;',
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/AreaName/Controller/MonthsToAdd',
  data: JSON.stringify({ 'months': months}),
  success: function (response) {
     alert("success.");
  }
});
});
```

In the browser console I see all the correct parameters  but MVC action doesn't receive the parameters. `array.count shows 0`. What did I miss here?

Comment: With `{ 'months': months}` you are passing an object which contains `months` as properties. But your controller accept `List` so change to `data: JSON.stringify(months),` to pass array from js

Comment: @user1672994 Thanks,  i tried that too, still the same

Comment: Is this an MVC  or a Razor pages application?

Comment: I've added the relevant tag

Comment: So you are trying to pass the data to the Page Action or to a Controller action?

Comment: So it's .NET core-mvc not razor-pages,i've updated the tags again

Comment: Can you post how data looks in the browser network trace (or you can capture in fiddler).

Comment: Now you are getting 500 error. So if you put the breakpoint in `MonthsToAdd` action then data is retrieved or not?

Comment: When i put a breakpoint and  $("#btnSave") click that takes me to MonthsToAdd action but `List<string> months` doesn't receive the array value post by ajax,

Comment: @user1672994 the 500 error is because inside `MonthsToAdd ` i have a service call that requires `months `

Comment: i think you miss something in your json. Your json must contains "months" property definition{
   "months":[
      "123456",
      "456789"
   ]
}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what worked on my end:

jQuery ajax method:

```
$.ajax({
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: 'json',
   type: 'POST',
   url: '@Url.Action("MonthsToAdd")',
   data: JSON.stringify(months),
   success: function (response) {
       alert("success.");
   }
});
```

Controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> MonthsToAdd([FromBody] List<string> months)

{
    // Add [FromBody]
}
```

Comment: @kukamuk I'm really glad I was able to help you!

Comment: Nice answer! Why exactly did the `[FromBody]` attribute make the difference? I'm asking because I am currently working on a large mvc api, and `[FromBody]` is nowhere to be seen.

Comment: @ShaiCohen This is required for the model binder to work in .net core (I think 2.0 or later). A really good article on this topic can be found [here](https://andrewlock.net/model-binding-json-posts-in-asp-net-core/).

Comment: "which you could previously do in ASP.NET 4/MVC 5." ... I'll show my dinosaur self out.